# Why I'm getting empty actual array from blocTest function?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, bloc, flutter-bloc, bloc-test

So I'm implementing blocTesting for my project and I'm getting an empty actual array from a specific feature.

***share_bloc_test.dart***
Below is the code for the blocFunction that is returning the empty actual array.

```dart
    group('ShareDisconnectGrantor', () {
      blocTest<ShareBloc, ShareState>(
        'emits [ShareLoadSuccess] '
        'state when successfully disconnected grantor',
        seed: () => ShareLoadSuccess(ConnectedUsersModel(List<ConnectedUserModel>.filled(1, ConnectedUserModel(1234, '1234', '1234')), List<ConnectedUserModel>.filled(1, ConnectedUserModel(1234, '1234', '1234'))), connectModel: ConnectModel('1234', dateTime, dateTime, dateTime, '1234', '1234')),
        setUp: () {
          when(
            shareRepositoryMock.disconnectFromGrantor(1234, 1234),
          ).thenAnswer(
            (_) => Future<ConnectedUsersModel>.value(ConnectedUsersModel(List<ConnectedUserModel>.filled(1, ConnectedUserModel(1234, '1234', '1234')), List<ConnectedUserModel>.filled(1, ConnectedUserModel(1234, '1234', '1234')))),
          );
        },
        build: () => ShareBloc(
            authenticationBloc: AuthenticationBloc(
                authenticationRepository: authenticationRepositoryMock),
            shareRepository: shareRepositoryMock),
        act: (ShareBloc bloc) => bloc.add(
          const ShareDisconnectGrantor(1234, 1234),
        ),
        expect: () => [
          ShareLoadSuccess(ConnectedUsersModel(List<ConnectedUserModel>.filled(1, ConnectedUserModel(1234, '1234', '1234')), List<ConnectedUserModel>.filled(1, ConnectedUserModel(1234, '1234', '1234'))), connectModel: ConnectModel('1234', dateTime, dateTime, dateTime, '1234', '1234')),
        ],
      );
    });
```

***share_bloc.dart***
Below is the code for the function corresponding to the event the above code is associated with

```dart
  Future<void> _onDisconnectGrantor(
      ShareDisconnectGrantor event, Emitter<ShareState> emit) async {
    if (state is ShareLoadSuccess) {
      final ShareLoadSuccess _currentState = state as ShareLoadSuccess;
      final ConnectedUsersModel _shareUsers = await shareRepository
          .disconnectFromGrantor(event.userId, event.grantorId);

      return emit(_currentState.copyWith(shareUsers: _shareUsers));
    }
  }
```

***share_state.dart***
Below is the code for state for the above bloctest function

```dart
part of 'share_bloc.dart';

abstract class ShareState extends Equatable {
  const ShareState();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => <Object?>[];
}

class ShareInitial extends ShareState {}

class ShareGranteeSuccess extends ShareState {}

class ShareGranteeFailure extends ShareState {
  final KBMException exception;
  const ShareGranteeFailure({required this.exception});
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => <Object?>[exception];
}

class ShareGrantorSuccess extends ShareState {}

class ShareGrantorFailure extends ShareState {
  final KBMException exception;
  const ShareGrantorFailure({required this.exception});
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => <Object?>[exception];
}

class ShareConnectSuccess extends ShareState {}

class ShareConnectFailure extends ShareState {
  final KBMException exception;
  const ShareConnectFailure({required this.exception});
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => <Object?>[exception];
}

class ShareLoadSuccess extends ShareState {
  final ConnectedUsersModel shareUsers;
  final ConnectModel? connectModel;
  final bool isGrantor;

  const ShareLoadSuccess(this.shareUsers, {this.connectModel, this.isGrantor = false});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => <Object?>[shareUsers, connectModel, isGrantor];

  ShareLoadSuccess copyWith({
    ConnectedUsersModel? shareUsers,
    ConnectModel? connectModel,
    bool? isGrantor,
  }) {
    return ShareLoadSuccess(
      shareUsers ?? this.shareUsers,
      connectModel: connectModel ?? this.connectModel,
      isGrantor: isGrantor ?? this.isGrantor,
    );
  }
}

class ShareGrantorAborted extends ShareState {}

class ShareSyncInProgress extends ShareState {
  final ConnectModel? connectModel;

  const ShareSyncInProgress({this.connectModel});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => <Object?>[connectModel];
}
```

I kinda have no ideas what might be the issue here. If anyone knows what might be happening please help...

Comment: is your initial state ShareLoadSuccess? if not it won't emit the new state. Also have you used Equatable to override the default equality?

Comment: @SankethB.K Yes

Comment: @SankethB.K I'm adding that state via seed

Comment: i am guessing since the state you are trying to emit is same as your current state (supplied from seed) it's not emitting the new state.

Comment: I've tried keeping them different as well

Comment: Can you share the code in which you have defined bloc states

Comment: Have you overridden the equality for ConnectedUsersModel?

Comment: Yes I have overriden that equality

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245295/discussion-between-sanketh-b-k-and-nike).